# When did Rumplestiltskin learn of Pan's origin?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

During the course of season three, we learn that Rumplestiltskin has run across Peter Pan before, when

> Pan tried to take Baelfire as a child.

But during this encounter, Rumple either does not know, or does not acknowledge Pan's true identity.

In *Think Good Thoughts*, when we learn Pan's identity, Rumple is not present at the time of Pan's creation.

During Rumple's present-day visit to Neverland, Rumple seems to know of Pan's identity.

**When/how did Rumplestiltskin learn of Peter Pan's former identity?**

Comment: if you already hid spoilers, why not just not hide more spoilers instead of stressing yourself to say things like 'when we learn Pan's identity' ?

Answer (score 5):

As the Shadow drags Rumple away, it stops for a moment and even points back so Rumple can watch the transformation of Pan.

You can see it here:

Comment: thanks. when i watched it originally, i thought the shadow had taken rumple further away by the time the green mist hit malcolm

Answer (score 2):

Rumpelstiltskin was definitely there at the time that Peter Pan was created.

Going to Never Never Land was Rumpelstiltskin idea, which his father goes along with. Once there, his dad realizes he's too old, and adults don't belong there. He can't even fly. However, the shadow shows up, and tries to take young Rumple away.

His father has a chance to save his son, but he chooses not to. He tells Rumple that he wants to be young forever, and lets go and allows the shadow to take the kid. Rumple drops his doll -- which he has named "Peter Pan", right as his father turns back into his younger self.

Even if Rumple hadn't seen it, when a young boy, named Peter Pan, who presumably looks a bit like a younger Rumple, and never grows up, becomes the king of Never Never Land, Rumpelstiltskin is smart enough to figure it out.